# When does a power semigroup have a zero, and what can the zero be?

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $S$ be a semigroup. The power semigroup of $S$ is the set $P(S)=2^S\setminus\lbrace\varnothing\rbrace $ with the operation $$AB=\lbrace ab\ |\ a\in A,\ b\in B\rbrace.$$

This operation is associative so the algebraic structure is a semigroup.

This semigroup can have a zero element. I've found the following examples.

> $(a)$ If $S$ has a zero element $0$, then $\lbrace0\rbrace$ is the zero element of $P(S)$.
>
> $(b)$ If $G$ is a group, then $G$ is the zero element of $P(G).$ Conversely, if $S$ is a semigroup, and $S$ is the zero element of $P(S)$, then $S$ is a group.
>
> $(c)$ If $G$ is a group, then add a new identity element $1_1$ to $G$ to obtain a monoid $G_1=G\cup\lbrace 1_1\rbrace$ in which the multiplication is left unchanged on $G$ and the rest of products are defined by $1_1x=x1_1=x.$ Then $G$ is the zero element of $P(G_1)$. We can then define $G_n$ to be the monoid obtained by adding a new identity element $1_k$ to $G$ $n$ times (that is for $k=1,\ldots,n$). $G$ is also the zero element of $P(G_n).$
>
> $(d)$ To obtain an example that doesn't have a zero and isn't a monoid, we can take $G_\omega=G\cup\lbrace1_1,1_2,\ldots\rbrace$ where $1_k$ are pairwise different and $1_k$ is the identity element of $G\cup\lbrace1_1,\ldots,1_{k}\rbrace.$ We can define such a semigroup $G_{\iota}$ for any ordinal number $\iota$ and always $G$ will be the zero element of $P(G_\iota).$

I suspect there are more examples, but I don't know how to find them. I would like to have a theorem of the form

> $P(S)$ has a zero element iff $\phi(S)$. Then the zero element is $\psi(S)$.

where $\phi(S)$ is a simple and edifying formula taking a semigroup as its argument, and $\psi(S)$ is a function that takes a semigroup and gives a subset of the semigroup.

In the other direction, let's suppose $I\subseteq S$ is the zero element of $P(S).$ This means that for any $X\subseteq S$, we have $XI=IX=I.$ This is equivalent to $xI=Ix=I$ for any $x\in S.$ This condition, if I'm not mistaken, implies the following conditions.

> $(1)$ $I$ is both the smallest left ideal of $S$ and the smallest right ideal of $S$.
>
> $(2)$ $I$ is an $\mathscr L$-class of $S;$ $I$ is an $\mathscr R$-class of $S;$ $I$ is a $\mathscr J$-class of $S$.
>
> $(3)$ $I$ is a subgroup of $S$.

I'm not sure if these conditions, in conjunction, suffice to make $I$ the zero element of $S$. I suspect not. Could you please make the picture clearer for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right. More simply: $I$ is a zero in $P(S)$ if and only if $I$ is an ideal of $S$ and a subgroup of $S$. Indeed, if $I$ is a zero, it must be a subgroup and an ideal as you wrote yourself. On the other hand, if $I$ is an ideal and a subgroup, then for every $x$ in $S$, $Ix$ is a left ideal of $S$ contained in $I$, hence it is a left ideal of $I$, so $Ix=I$ (a group has only one left ideal). Similarly, $xI=I$. So $I$ is a zero.

Comment: Right, thanks a lot! But which semigroups have such an ideal? Are there any examples other than the ones I mentioned? Can we characterize such semigroups?

Comment: Here is a general construction. Take any semigroup $T$, any group $G$ and any homomorphism $\phi: T\to G$. Consider $S$ the disjoint union of $T$ and $G$ with operation * that coincides with the native operations on $T,G$ and $t*g=\phi(t)g$, $g*t=g\phi(t)$ for every $g\in G$, $t\in T$. Then $S$ is a semigroup (the semilattice of $T$ and $G$) and $G$ is an ideal of $S$. These are not all semigroups with subgroups which are ideals, but it gives a lot of examples.

Comment: Your examples are like that where $T$ is the chain of idempotents ($\{e_1,...,e_n\}$, $e_ie_j=e_je_i=e_i$ if $i\le j$),and $\phi$ is a homomorphism that maps everything to 1. 

Comment: Thank you, I see. Could you give an example of a semigroup that has a subgroup as an ideal but isn't of this kind? Perhaps I should explain why I'm asking these questions. I'm trying to prove that if $S$ is a semigroup and $G$ is a group, then $P(S)\cong P(G)$ implies $S\cong G$. Clearly, if $P(S)\cong P(G)$, then $S$ has a subgroup as an ideal, so if I knew what such semigroups are, my job would be easier.

Comment: Take any semigroup $S$ with 0 such that $S\setminus \{0\}$ is not a subsemigroup, then $S$ is an example. 

Comment: Oh, sorry. I should have asked about semigroups without zero.

Comment: I think that looking for more and more complicated examples is not the way to prove what you want. I think you know enough to be able to prove it (or find a relatively easy counterexample). 

Comment: Note if S is a finite monoid with group of units H, then P(S) has group of units H. So if P(S) is isomorphic to P(G) then G is isomorphic to H and for cardinality reasons S=G. So the question is easy if G is finite. 


Comment: @Ben: You are correct. I thought the OP probably could find it out himself. 

Comment: @Ben, thank you. Yes, I knew that. From the above it also follows easily that the answer is "yes" if $S$ doesn't have any idempotents apart from $1$. I believe the answer is "yes" for any pair $G,S,$ but I still do not see a proof. 

Comment: If $S$ is a monoid, then the group of units of $\mathcal P(S)$ consists of the one-element sets $\{u\}$ s.t. $u$ is a unit of $S$ (and hence it is isomorphic to the group of units of $S$). Since (i) a semigroup isomorphism whose domain is a monoid, is a fortiori a monoid isomorphism and (ii) monoid isomorphisms are unit-preserving, this suffices to show that if $S$ is globally isomorphic to a group $G$, then $S$ is itself a group and isomorphic to $G$. See also [https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456513/456790#456790] and the refs therein.